# Extracting Weights and Feature names from Logistic Regression Model in Spark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a cross validator model which has estimator as pipeline object. The model trained is OneVsAll with Logistic regression as the base classifier for OneVsAll.

Here is how the best model in fitted Cross_validated model looks like

```
jpsa_lr.cvModel.bestModel.stages
Out[281]:
[StringIndexer_4c8399b4ed29d68bc275,
 Tokenizer_48ae8fc24affa2e6a68e,
 StopWordsRemover_4b7996719495950017eb,
 CountVectorizer_444c8ac83adb883350a1,
 IDF_4e0793e75252aa6a2477,
 OneVsRestModel_4941951599f4c8a07352]
```

This is how I trained:

```
 evaluator = MulticlassClassificationEvaluator(metricName="f1",\
            labelCol=self.pipeline.getStages()[5].getLabelCol(), predictionCol=self.pipeline.getStages()[5].getPredictionCol())

        # Declare the CrossValidator, which runs model tuning for us.
        cv = CrossValidator(estimator=self.pipeline, evaluator=evaluator, estimatorParamMaps=self.paramGrid,numFolds=5)

        # Training the cross validator model
        self.cvModel=cv.fit(self.jpsa_train)
```

Where Pipeline object was the object of above transformers and estimators.

Now I want to get the weights of the logistic model from cvModel.bestModel.

I have checked this answer here and tried the following:

[Extract variable weight from spark pipeline logistic model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35911831/extract-variable-weight-from-spark-pipeline-logistic-model)

```
cvModel.bestModel.weights 
cvModel.bestModel.weight

cvModel.bestModel.stages[5].getClassifier().weights
cvModel.bestModel.stages[5].getClassifier().weight
```

But none of them have the attributes specified. While the above answer seems to suggest it has. I even looked at the documentation for OnevsAll, logistic, crossvalidator and none of them have weight or intercept attribute.

Any suggestions to get the weight vector and the corresponding feature names?

Comment: What version of Spark is this?

Comment: @ Paul Black 2.0.2

Comment: @Baktaawar Were you able to figure it out?